# Difference between RxJS5 subscription and observer

Tags: rxjs5

I see some question/answers relating to Rx Subscriptions/Observers but they may be for older versions of Rx and also not for RxJS, which may conform to a different API.

I was under the impression that subscriptions/subscribers and observers were all the same. If you look at the docs, they are in different adjacent sections, but seem to be exactly the same:

Observer:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observer

Subscription:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscription

what the heck is the difference? Can someone given an example with a practical difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

> An Observer is a consumer of values delivered by an Observable.

So basically the observer receives the values emitted by a stream.

> A Subscription is an object that represents a disposable resource, usually the execution of an Observable.

A subscription is basically just a *"fact"* that a certain observer currently receives data, if you unsubscribe a subscription, both the stream and the observer will still exist, they are just not connected any more.

---

A real-world metaphor mixed with pseudo-code: **Newspaper**

**Stream**: This would be the production-chain of the newspaper (involing the publishing company *creating the content* and the printing house *printing the paper*)

```
const newsPaper$ = Observable.interval(DAILY)
    .switchMapTo(date => publishingCompany.createContent(date))
    .switchMapTo(content => printingHouse.printPaper(content))
    .publish()
    .refCount();
```

**Observer**: This would be the reader/recipient, that *guy with a bathrobe* that picks up the newspaper in his front-yard every morning to read it.

```
const bathrobeGuy = {
    next: newsPaper => readPaper(newsPaper),
    error: errorMsg => complainAbout(errorMsg), // the bathrobe guy will be so angry, the he unsubscribes the paper
    complete: () => subscribeToDifferentNewsPaper()
}
```

**Subscription**: This is the news-paper-subscription - the *delivery-boy* throwing the newspaper into each front-yard every morning.

```
// this will activate the "delivery boy"
const paperSubscription = newsPaper$.subscribe(bathrobeGuy);
```

**Unsubscribing**: When the bathrobe-guy decides to not want the paper any more, he can unsubscribe the paper and the delivery-boy will not deliver any paper any more. However the observer(the bathrobe-guy) and the newspaper-production still exist, but they have simply no relationship any more.

```
paperSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

An **Observer** is an object with a set of callbacks that are executed when you subscribe to an Observable. In other words, when you call `subscribe` you pass an object of type Observer. Even when you only pass a callback, internally rxjs is creating an Observer with your callback as the `next` property. Other properties are `error` and `complete`.

A **Subscription** is the `return` type of the call `subscribe`, and its only purpose is to be able to call `subscription.unsubscribe()` in order to not listen to that subscription anymore. The Observer functions (next, error, complete) will no longer be called.

```
var myObserver = {
  next: (val) => {},
  error: (err) => {},
  complete: () => {}
};

var mySubscription: Subscription = myObservable.subscribe(myObserver);

// then, if later you want to unsubscribe:

mySubscription.unsubscribe()
```