# observer in Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have just started with Observable and Observer pattern, I went through various site and found that Observable is producer and Observer is consumer. Then when I was going through below code, I got confused on the meaning of observer.

```
 export class AppComponent {
 private data:Observable;
 private dataObserver:Observer;

 constructor(private http: Http) {
 this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer);
 }
```

So can anyone please help in providing meaning of observer, when you are creating new Observable object.

**this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between RxJS5 subscription and observer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949355/difference-between-rxjs5-subscription-and-observer)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the Observable constructor is a callback method that is called for with an observer that subscribes to that observable. So the observer is not available when the Observable is being created.

You can find more info here:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-constructor-constructor

> The function that is called when the Observable is initially
>   subscribed to. This function is given a Subscriber, to which new
>   values can be nexted, or an error method can be called to raise an
>   error, or complete can be called to notify of a successful completion.

and here
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html

> You can create an Observable from scratch by using the Create
>   operator. You pass this operator a function that accepts the observer
>   as its parameter. Write this function so that it behaves as an
>   Observable — by calling the observer’s onNext, onError, and
>   onCompleted methods appropriately.
>
> A well-formed finite Observable must attempt to call either the
>   observer’s onCompleted method exactly once or its onError method
>   exactly once, and must not thereafter attempt to call any of the
>   observer’s other methods.